# mysql unexpected syntax error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So I have the following query (There are three tables, therefore the joins)

```
SELECT AVG(survey_responses.survey_response), survey_responders.province, 
survey_questions.question 
FROM survey_responses 
INNER JOIN survey_responders on survey_responses.id = survey_responders.id
INNER JOIN survey_questions on survey_responders.id = survey_questions.id
GROUP BY survey_questions.question;
```

Now there are six questions and ten provinces, but it will only list five questions and five provinces, why is it doing that?

Comment: So it's not a syntax error then?

Comment: We'd need to know your underlying data to understand what's going on.  However, my guess is that you may want outer, rather than inner, joins: see [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for more information.  Note also that you're selecting the ungrouped column `survery_responders.province` without an aggregate function: MySQL will indeterminately select only *one* value from each group.

Comment: Use aliases to join tables

Comment: first join do anything but not the thing

Comment: List the tables and the data you want to get!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your query outputs a list of five questions and five provinces instead of six questions and ten provinces because some of the id's can't be found into it's corresponding id to the table or some of the fields have no relation to the other fields of the other tables. If you want to retrieve all rows, use the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
      AVG(survey_responses.survey_response), 
      survey_responders.province, 
      survey_questions.question 
FROM survey_responses 
LEFT JOIN survey_responders on survey_responses.id = survey_responders.id
LEFT JOIN survey_questions on survey_responders.id = survey_questions.id
GROUP BY survey_questions.question;
```

Comment: How can you possibly know this without seeing the underlying data?